# Hibernate: How Discriminator Column works in case when there is no physical columns or value present for differentiating instance?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping, discriminator

I am trying to understand existing code which is new for me as i have used discrimnatercolumn and values which has actual physical column names in database as well as physical values but in this existing code there is no physical columns or values but still it is working.

```
@Table(name = "ADRESSE")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISC", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING,length=20)
public class Address{
 ID
}
```

There is no column with name DISC in database. Does this means it will discriminate on base of ID?

```
@Table(name = "POST_ADRESSE")
@Indexed
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "POSTADRESSE")
public class PostAdresse extends Adresse {
  //Address1 Address 2
}
```

There is no value name PostAdresse. There is no column with name PostAdresse. The only common point is ID which is common in both Adresse and PostAdresse

When we check (addresse instanceof postadresse); then on what basis it discriminates and return correct object i.e how it is working exactly?

Answer (score 0):

For your case, the `@DiscriminatorColumn` has no effect because your inheritance strategy is `InheritanceType.JOINED`.

`@DiscriminatorColumn` works in case the inheritance strategy is `InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE`